# PySpark: Filter dataframe by substring in other table

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, a and b:

a:

```
+-----+---------+
| word|frequency|
+-----+---------+
|  git|        5|
|stack|       10|
|match|       15|
|other|        3|
+-----+---------+
```

b:

```
+-------------+---------+
|         word|frequency|
+-------------+---------+
|       github|        5|
|       match |        2|
|stackoverflow|       10|
|      b_entry|        7|
+-------------+---------+
```

I would like to filter out all rows from dataframe a where the word column is equal to or a substring of any row from b, so the desired output is:

```
+-----+---------+
| word|frequency|
+-----+---------+
|other|        3|
+-----+---------+
```

I know there are functions a.word.contains(), a.word.like(), a.word.rlike(), etc that can help me test conditions if a.word has a substring. The issue with these is that I would end up with the rows of b that contain values of a.word, instead of the rows of a that are contained by b.word. Are there any functions to help test if a.word is a substring of another table?

Ideally, a solution would be able to operate on the two tables together instead of directly iterating over the values, eg SQL Join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains()` in the join condition with `left_anti` as the join type.
A **left anti join** returns all rows from the first table which do not have a match in the second table.

```
df_a.show()
+-----+---------+                                                               
| word|frequency|
+-----+---------+
|  git|        5|
|stack|       10|
|match|       15|
|other|        3|
+-----+---------+
```

```
df_b.show()
+-------------+-----------+
|       word_1|frequency_1|
+-------------+-----------+
|       github|          5|
|        match|          2|
|stackoverflow|         10|
|      b_entry|          7|
+-------------+-----------+
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_a.join(df_b, (df_b.word_1.contains(df_a.word)), "left_anti").show()
+-----+---------+
| word|frequency|
+-----+---------+
|other|        3|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm